# Store Selected Values From Drop Down List in Session Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, session-variables

I am trying to store the selected value of an item in my drop down list into a session variable after selecting it and pressing a button to add it to a session variable.  My question is, is there a way to store multiple selections into different session variable with the same drop down list.  Each session variable has the same value and I am unsure how to save each selected value into a new  session variable.

```
protected void DropDownListAddNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["selectionOne"] = DropDownListAddNumber.Items.FindByValue(DropDownListAddNumber.SelectedValue);
    Session["selectionTwo"] = DropDownListAddNumber.Items.FindByValue(DropDownListAddNumber.SelectedValue);
    Session["selectionThree"] = DropDownListAddNumber.Items.FindByValue(DropDownListAddNumber.SelectedValue);
    Session["selectionFour"] = DropDownListAddNumber.Items.FindByValue(DropDownListAddNumber.SelectedValue);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? Your example stores the currently selected item into 4 different session variables. asp:dropdownlists cannot have multiple selections - you'd need a third-party control for that

Comment: What I am confused about is how to store each selected value in some sort of list or session variable so I can have access to to that selected value. So if I want to grab the second value and print it out, I can do so. With only one dropdownlist, the latest selected value get stored in each of the four session variables I have created. Any help would great?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If multi-select is not your question, storing it by each variable will not scale well. If you want to store each selection into the Session, you can store a List of strings into the session. (taking advantage of the fact that the items are stored in the order we insert them in a list)

```
protected void DropDownListAddNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 List<string> sessionList = GetSessionVariable();
 sessionList.Add(DropDownListAddNumber.Items.FindByValue
                 (DropDownListAddNumber.SelectedValue));
}

// you can access the selected values from the list
// if sessionList.Any(), then sessionList.Last() will contain 
// the last selected value.. etc.

private List<string> GetSessionVariable()
{
 var list = Session["SelectionValuesList"] as List<string>;

 if (list == null)
 {
  list = new List<string>();
  Session["SelectionValuesList"] = list;
 } 

 return list;
}
```

OR

if you still want to use multiple session variables, you need to do some sort of counter.
multiple variables will be created. this is error prone.

```
int lastCounter = 0;

protected void DropDownListAddNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ++lastCounter;
    Session["selection" + lastCounter] = DropDownListAddNumber.Items
                                        .FindByValue(DropDownListAddNumber.SelectedValue);
}

// you can access last value as
// var lastSelectedValue = Session["selection" + lastCounter];
```

Comment: What I am confused about is how to store each selected value in some sort of list or session variable so I can have access to to that selected value.  So if I want to grab the second value and print it out, I can do so.  With only one dropdownlist, the latest selected value get stored in each of the four session variables I have created.  Any help would great?

Comment: still not clear. do you want to store multiple values selected in 1 shot OR do you want to store single selected values every time they are selected?

Comment: I want to store single selected values every time they are selected from one drop down list.  For example, I select one value, press a button, then  store that value some how.  With the same drop drop down list, i want to make another selection, press the same button, and store that value.  The problem I am facing is each time I select a value and press a button to store it, each variable has the same selected value.

Comment: For that my list based session approach should work. Did you try? Instead of doing findbyvale, just use selected value.

Comment: List based session approach works. Thanks very much!!